# How much RAM for Intel HAXM (Android SDK)?

Tags: android, sdk, intel, haxm

I have 16GB RAM and installer recommends 2GB. I set it to 4GB. Will I see any improvements for "Hello world" programs is I set 2,4 and 8B?

Comment: I also would like to know this answer...